# Best way and flexible ways to communicate server networking in android?

Tags: android, android-networking

I read from many blogs about it, i found 3 way to communicate server in android.

1. java.net (using socket)
2. org.apache.http
3. android.net

I'm new in android networking, i want to learn fast choosing only 1 steps,
my target API is 8, they said that when using API 8, using org.apache is good,
but they also said that java.net or native style is best because u can implements
all using native style, any suggestion from the 3 choices above, and what are pros and cons
from the 3 choices, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and most recent way to do a communication between an Android device and a server is through [volley library](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) this has been introduced recently in google conference and there was a proposal to make this library the default Android library for networking, it makes networking faster and easier.

The library is supported from API 8 onwards, you can watch the conference video provided in the previous link to know more about the structure, and here are the some tutorials you can refer to it. [tutorial 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/), [tutorial 2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library).

good luck.

Comment: Volley Library is already part in the SDK or separate library for now?

Comment: currently, it is separate. you need to download the library and include it to your project. but I guess soon in the few next updates it will be part of the SDK.